Syntax error at input 'end of line without line continuation', Pine Script, TradingView
//@version=5
// Display correlation matrix with labels
var label corr_matrix = label.new(x=na, y=na, text="", style=label.style_label_down, size=size.normal, color=color.white)
maxBarIndex = ta.highest(bar_index, 1)
if (bar_index == maxBarIndex)
    label.set_xy(corr_matrix, bar_index, high)
    label.set_text(corr_matrix,
        "Corr 1-2: " + str.tostring(correlation_1_2, format.percent) + "\n" +
        "Corr 1-3: " + str.tostring(correlation_1_3, format.percent) + "\n" +
        "Corr 1-4: " + str.tostring(correlation_1_4, format.percent) + "\n" +
        "Corr 2-3: " + str.tostring(correlation_2_3, format.percent) + "\n" +
        "Corr 2-4: " + str.tostring(correlation_2_4, format.percent) + "\n" +
        "Corr 3-4: " + str.tostring(correlation_3_4, format.percent)
    )

On Line 46 "label.set_text(corr_matrix," of the code it gives me a syntax error at input 'end of line without line continuation'. The indentations don't look wrong to me that's why I'm not really sure where the issue is stemming from. This has me stumped, is there any way to fix this?

Try putting a \  after corr_matrix,. It allows a long command to span multiple lines for readability. If the error continues on the same line, add the same slash to each of the "Corr... " + "\n" + lines too

When wrapping lines, the new line must begin with one or several (different from multiple of 4) spaces.
if (bar_index == maxBarIndex)
    label.set_xy(corr_matrix, bar_index, high)
    label.set_text(corr_matrix,
         "Corr 1-2: " + str.tostring(correlation_1_2, format.percent) + "\n" +
         "Corr 1-3: " + str.tostring(correlation_1_3, format.percent) + "\n" +
         "Corr 1-4: " + str.tostring(correlation_1_4, format.percent) + "\n" +
         "Corr 2-3: " + str.tostring(correlation_2_3, format.percent) + "\n" +
         "Corr 2-4: " + str.tostring(correlation_2_4, format.percent) + "\n" +
         "Corr 3-4: " + str.tostring(correlation_3_4, format.percent)
     )

